# Redireccionar a vista error de ruta en laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Es posible que cuando una ruta digitada por url esté mal copiada, no se redireccione a esta página [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Si no a una vista donde pueda manejar el error de otra manera? por decir `return view('paginadondemuestroerrores')`

Comment: En laravel 5 debería funcionar crear una carpeta `errors` dentro de `views`  y dentro de ella una vista `404.blade.php`  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para devolver una vista personalizada ante error `404` como lo dice la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#http-exceptions) bastaría con crear una nueva vista `404.blade.php` la ruta sería

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

Comment: Un detalle muy pequeño: Sería mejor si apuntaras tu enlace a la documentación de 5.4

Comment: @Shaz esa parte de la documentación no varía en las versiones posteriores a 5.0 como la etiqueta dice laravel 5 opté por la versión solo 5.0 ,quizá el OP no esté usando la ultima versión de laravel Aún.

Comment: Lo que dices en cuanto a la variación de los de la documentación es cierto, sin embargo me parece más conveniente mostrarle al OP "la última versión", ya he visto varios casos en lo que los OP no sabían que había algo más allá de 5.0 o 5.1. En ese orden de ideas entonces podrías sugerir la documentación de la versión LTS actual (5.1).